# How using the current contents of the list in a function running in the loop?

Tags: python, function, variables, while-loop, multiprocessing

I try to use multiprocessing in this way:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

added = []

def foo(i):
    added = []
       # do something 
       added.append(x[i])
    return added

if __name__ == '__main__':

h = 0
while len(added)<len(c): 

   pool = Pool(4)
   result = pool.imap_unordered(foo, c)      
   added.append(result[-1])

   pool.close()
   pool.join()

   h = h + 1
```

Multiprocessing takes place in the while-loop, and in the `foo` function, the
`added` list is created. In each subsequent step `h` in the loop, the list`added` should be incremented by subsequent values, and the current list `added` should be used in the function`foo`. Is it possible to pass the current contents of the list to the function in each subsequent step of the loop? Because in the above code, the `foo` function creates the new contents of the `added` list from scratch each time. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).  The rough idea is to construct one of these in your main process, pass it to the child processes, and each `foo()` invocation can call `put(x[i])` to add a value to the queue.

The main process will then read the queue to collect the results.

Comment: It's a difficult thing because I have never used `queue 'before. I need to read a bit. Thanks for te hint ;)

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski: Sure.  Just think of `multiprocessing.Queue` as similar to a list which works between multiple processes (whereas a regular list does not).